# How to set a date/ get a date for Datepicker in codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I can't manage to set a date and to get a date of Datepicker in code behind(C#)
does anyone have informations to give me about this ? thanks in advance!

```
  <input id="datepicker" value="01/01/2011" type="text"/>



$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Since my Picker is
<input id="datepicker0" type="text"/> in my aspx...
i tried to get access to this by writting datepicker0."anything" but it does not work

Comment: can you post your code by editing the question?

Comment: Actually if i add runat="server" to my input, i do have access to the picker in codebehind but the picker no longer works... i don't understand why...

Answer (score 6):

```
<input id="datepicker0" type="text" name="datepickernm"/>
```

You can get the value from below code in the codebehind:

```
String text = Page.Request.Form["datepickernm"]
```

Comment: so this should work to get date in code behind but to set a date ? thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

Use an ASP textbox control:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="txtDate"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>').datepicker();
</script>
```

This way you could get and set the value from code behind.

Comment: The best solution for complete functionality.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar control in asp.net will provide you with the functionality you need. Drag the control from the Toolbox in Visual Studio

then access the Calendar control from codebehind using the ID

Answer (score -1):

The above method does not allow me to set the value from the code behind. I am only able to get the date from the code behind.

When i remove the javascript form the html header, it seems to works.. i think that the javascript is overriding the value in the textbox.