# Datepicker is not working when adding runat="server"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, datepicker, runatserver

I am referring to this site http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ for datepicker and I am coding exactly like the source code given. Those coding is working fine.

**But..**

When I am adding **runat="server"** inside this piece of code `<input type="text" id="datepicker">` my calendar won't show up when clicking the `TextBox`. I need to put **runat="server"** so that I am able to use it at behind code.

Any suggestion from you guys would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: consult your console for errors

Comment: You cannot get js components in code behind directly. Look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032068/how-to-set-a-date-get-a-date-for-datepicker-in-codebehind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a correct way to do it.

**For ASP.Net design**

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="datepicker"></asp:TextBox>`

**On client server side**

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker();
});`

put `$("[id$=datepicker]").datepicker();` instead of `$('#<%= datepicker.ClientID %>').datepicker();` then calendar will be shown up and able to call the **datepicker** in code behind.

Answer (score 4):

When **runat=server** is added with a master page then it generate Default style id with master page.. So to avoid it try **ClientIDMode="Static"**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

with out ClientIDMode='Static' the generated HTML is

```
<input type="text" id="MainContent_datepicker" name="ctl00$MainContent$datepicker">
```

for more info use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)  for mozilla firefox by **inspecting Element With firebug**

Answer (score 0):

When the textbox is runat="server" in the view source you can find the name of the textbox having a dynamic prefix generated.

So in your JavaScript you are not supposed to use the id attributed specified in the tag rather you should use <%=IdAttributeValue.ClientID%> which will give the generated ID.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("body").delegate("#<%=datepicker.ClientID%>", "focusin", function () {
$(this).datepicker();
 });
 });
  </script>
```